# Any alternatives to using cursor in SQL procedure in Oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I give the SQL few inputs and I need to get all the ID's and their count that doesn't satisfy the required criteria.

*I would like to know if there are there any alternatives to using cursor.*

```
DECLARE
   v_count            INTEGER;
   v_output           VARCHAR2 (1000);
   pc                 table1%ROWTYPE;
   unmarked_ids       EXCEPTION;
   dynamic_sql        VARCHAR (5000);
   cur                SYS_REFCURSOR;
   id                 pp.id%TYPE;
   pos                INTEGER;
BEGIN
   v_count := 0;
   SELECT *
     INTO pc
     FROM table1
    WHERE id = '&ID';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
      dynamic_sql :=
            'SELECT ID from pp
                    WHERE ( TO_CHAR(cdate, ''yyyy/mm/dd'') = 
                    TO_CHAR (:a, ''yyyy/mm/dd''))
                    AND aid IN (SELECT aid FROM ppd WHERE TO_CHAR(cdate, ''yyyy/mm/dd'') = 
                    TO_CHAR (:b, ''yyyy/mm/dd'')
                    AND cid = :c )
                    AND cid <> :d';
      OPEN cur FOR dynamic_sql USING pc.cdate, pc.cdate, pc.id, pc.id;
      LOOP
         FETCH cur INTO id;
         EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
         v_count := v_count + 1;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (' Id:' || id);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur;
   IF (v_count > 0)
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Count: ' || v_count || ' SQL: ' || dynamic_sql);
      RAISE unmarked_ids;
   END IF;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQL ended successfully');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN unmarked_ids
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Found ID's that not marked with the current id.');
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'No data found in table1 with the current id ' || '&ID');
END;
```

There are bind variables in the query. One of them is date, there are three more. 
The count and ID's are required to be shown which will later be reported.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL?  In the example you posted, nothing about the query is dynamic so there is no need to use dynamic SQL.  The fact that you appear to be doing dynamic SQL without using bind variables is rather more concerning than the fact that you're using a cursor to iterate over the results.  Are you actually doing something with the `ID` values that you fetch?  Or are you just counting them?

Comment: There are actually bind variables like date and some other things that I didn't mention in the query ( I put ... ). These ID's will be reported later if the SQL finds any with the count ( number of ID's )

Comment: So, in the actual code, `date1` is passed in as a bind variable rather than being hard-coded into the SQL statement as your example does?  I'm not sure what it means for the `ID` values to be "reported later if the SQL finds any with the count".  Can you explain that in a bit more detail?

Comment: Yes, there are bind variables in the actual SQL. These ID's will be given to a UC4 job which fails if it finds any ID's. Then the PROD support team will see those ID's and fix the issues. Those ID's are shown solely for supporting PROD support team.

Comment: OK, so the actual code looks different from the amended example and is actually using bind variables?  What is a "UC4 job" and how does this code give the set of `ID` values it finds to this job?

Comment: UC4 is a automation tool that executes SQL job ( It can execute any job/jobplans( which contains many jobs)). When UC4 executes this SQL job, it gets the output of the SQL job in a Report tab. Then the post-processing of UC4 kicks in to see if it finds any ID's in the Report tab. If it finds any ID's it returns a status code of 1 ( which is failure ) and ends the process flow. It if returns a status code of 0 it continues the process flow by executing the next job ( which can be anything, Java, SQL, Informatica / any other UC4 job )

Comment: How does the code you posted return the set of `ID` values to UC4?  Does it return a `SYS_REFCURSOR`?  A collection?  Do you run a separate query from UC4 that is supposed to be identical to the query you run in this PL/SQL block?

Comment: Yes, It is a SYS_REFCURSOR. I run this SQL Query in TOAD to see if it passes testing and then copy this SQL block to Form tab in UC4, then it does its job. I don't know how the return values are passed into Report Tab for UC4 when the SQL job is executed.

Comment: Is "this SQL query" the PL/SQL block you posted?  Or do you have a separate SQL statement?  Are you giving a SQL statement or a PL/SQL block to UC4?

Comment: The code that I have edited just now which is in the code section is the whole thing that I copy to UC4.

Comment: I am guessing that `:a` and `:b` and `:c` and `:d` are names of columns in `pp` and `ppd`, correct? Otherwise, this example doesn't really need dynamic SQL.

Comment: :a, :b, :c, and :d are values from pc "pc.cdate, pc.cdate, pc.id, pc.id" where pc is obtained from the following select query : "SELECT * INTO pc FROM table1 WHERE id = '&ID'; "

Answer (score 1):

You could store the rowid in a temporary table along with an index value (0...n) and then use a while loop to go through the index values and join to the real table using the rowid.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not saying this is a good idea! It is just one approach that I've seen used...

Comment: I've used this approach before, it can work and is faster than a cursor but comes with a bit of health warning